# JsonMappingException NOT getting thrown when it should

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class in Java that is generically typed.  It is supposed to return an object of type T after receiving some json.  I am using the following code to create the object:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
this.object = mapper.readValue(json, type);
```

This method throws a `JsonMappingException`, and should do so if the object isn't of the proper type.  The problem I'm running into (when unit testing) is that if I pass in json of an incorrect type, as long as both objects are pojos no exception is being thrown.  I am simply getting back an object of the correct type where all it's fields are null.

Why is the exception not getting thrown here?  If I pass in some json with a bunch of fields that don't exist on the type of object it should be mapping to, shouldn't I get an exception from that?

Comment: Do you maybe have `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` set?

Comment: This is the true answer... can you write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You possibly have:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

set somewhere, so jackson doesn't complain about the mismatch.

Comment: I do not have @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) anywhere and still when I assert on JsonMappingException in Junits I get AssertionFailure. an instance of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException <java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name cannot be null, empty or missing.> is a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: FYI: I'm throwing IllegalArgumentException when name is null. But my other deserializer for a different pojo, throws JsonMappingException like a charm (even that throws IllegalArgumentException)

Comment: from the one that throws JsonMappingException 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:210)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:177)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1474)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:260)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:125)

Comment: I dont see the above calls to wrap methods in the one that doesn't throw the expected JsonMappingException

Comment: @Gnana Please post a new question if your issue is different than this one.

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect Jackson to know JSON does not represent expected type? JSON data does not have type, beyond just basic Object/Array/scalars structure. So as long as structure is compatible things work, and this is by design.